# Android toolbar title, subtitle and back button not appearing despite setting properties

Tags: java, android, xml, android-support-library, android-toolbar

After creating a toolbar to replace an action bar, the toolbar is not producing the expected results. The toolbar itself appears with the specified colour as desired, but for some reason the title, subtitle and back button do not appear at all. The activity's theme has even been set to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`.

**layout/toolbar_turquoise.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_turquoise"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/turquoise"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

**TurquoiseActivity.java**

```
public class TurquoiseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null) {
            Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_turquoise);
            setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

            myToolbar.setTitle("Hello World");
            myToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
            myToolbar.setSubtitle("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
            myToolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
            upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000099"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        }

        FragmentTurquoise newFragment = new FragmentTurquoise();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

XML File:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/turquoise"
            android:minHeight="100dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java Class:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if(toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setTitle("Hello World");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
        toolbar.setSubtitle("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000099"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
    }
```